# External code files in visual basic express 2010

Tags: javascript, vb.net, external

to get to the point, Is there anyway to run code from external files? like a .js file for javascript.

Thanks!

to clarify:

So what I want to accomplish, is having an external file with a portion of my code in it, so I can clean things up a bit.

An example of exactly what I'm looking for, is a .js file for smallbasic. For those of you who know Javascript, here is what it looks like:

```
<script language="javascript" src="Program.js" ></script>
```

And then I have the Program.js file in the same folder with a bunch of code in it.

Here is some pseudo code to further clarify:

```
Extension.CallFile(Program.Directory + "/Menu.txt")
Once run through, then the program will continue:
Extension.CallFile(Program.Directory + "/Gamepad.txt")
```

As you can see, this would be extremely helpful for cleaning up the code.

Comment: I think you might have gotten to the point too quickly...  It would help to flesh out your question a little with some details: for example what will the code in the js file actually do?  What are some of your *actual use cases*?

Comment: Hard to tell if this is a solution for you, but [ClearScript](https://clearscript.codeplex.com/) can be used to run javascript, and provide hooks into your application by script.